# Why is dense format better than sparse format for small sizes?

Tags: matlab, memory, sparse-matrix

We consider the following code on Matlab with N an integer.

```
diag = 3*speye(N,N);           % diagonal
subd=-sparse(2:N,1:N-1,1,N,N);
A=diag+subd+2*subd';
C=full(A);
```

If I am not wrong, sparse format keeps only non-zero entries, so it needs less memory. I noticed that when N=2,...,6, the size of A is bigger than the size of C even if A is in sparse format. Can someone explain why ?

Comment: The sparse format has to store the location of the nonzeros - that can mean 3 numbers for each.  Sparse only starts saving memory when less than 30% of the values are nonzero.

Comment: For clarification, the MATLAB sparse format stores the value and the row index for each non-zero entry, and also stores a running total of the number of non-zeros per column. End result is the "average" number of stored entries per non-zero value often works out to be something between 2 and 3.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the answer ! Do you mean exactly less than 30% or was it an approximation ? If we take for example a 10x10 matrix that has hence 100 values, and only 31 of them have non-zero values then the sparse format will keep 3*31 = 93 values which is still less than 100 values. Did you mean 1/3 of the values ? Sorry for being boring, I am just curious

Comment: In my example given in the code, for N=7, 38% of the matrix is nonzero but sparse format is better

Comment: MATLAB uses the csc format (read its docs or standard WIKI article on sparse matrices).  For squarish matrices that's a bit more compact, so the 38% sounds reasonable.  BUT, for calculation purposes you might want to go even smaller.  Multiplication with sparse matrices is more involved, so a 5% sparsity is a better rule-of-thumb.

Comment: A 10x10 sparse matrix with 31 non-zero values in MATLAB would take 31 values + 31 row indexes + 11 running column totals = 73 storage locations needed (not including the mxArray header itself). A full double would of course take 100 storage locations. Each storage location stores a 64-bit double or 64-bit integer. For this particular size using a sparse matrix isn't justified because you are not saving that much storage and the increased complexity of working with it will have a speed performance hit.